# Make Python ignore certain code in editor?

Tags: python, editor, geany

I'm using Geany which lets me add manual fold points using ";{" and ";}". Of course Python doesn't like this and gives an error, is there any way to get this working?

Edit: Comments make Geany ignore it and removes the folding.

Comment: Prepend it with a `#`?

Comment: ... use comments?

Comment: Yeah, looks like this features was designed with C-like languages in mind...

Comment: It appears you can [set your own characters](https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/adding_fold_points). Perhaps using triple-quoted strings? i.e. `'''` and `'''`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Tried using the linked method but can't find the SciTe commands in geany.conf, and adding them doesn't work. `'''` adds a fold point but the code inside is ignored.

Comment: Yeah, it should because that is a comment. I think you could maybe just use a semicolon: ';'

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either, `;` gives a syntax error.

Comment: How do you add these folks marks?